# скрипт который возьмет строки из одного файла и соединит их со строками других файлов

Tags: perl

Есть 20 файлов - `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt` .... `20.txt` с разным количеством строк (общее кол-во строк во всех 20-ти файлах - 36 тысяч).
И есть один большой файл также с 36 000 строк - `big.txt`.

Задача: подставить строки из большого файла в начало строк всех 20 файлов.

Пример:

В большом файле строки:

```
привет дядя ваня;
пока дядя ваня;
здравствуй дядя ваня;
```

В 20-ти файлах строки:

```
милиция хорошо
полиция хорошо
пожарники хорошо
```

В результате в 20-ти файлах должно быть:

```
привет дядя ваня;милиция хорошо
пока дядя ваня;полиция хорошо
здравствуй дядя ваня;пожарники хорошо
```

Дополнительное условие: объединять эти 20 файлов нельзя.

Comment: Это тестовое задание, да?

Comment: Ну напишите такой скрипт, местные не против :)

Comment: Открываем `big`, открываем `1`, построчно соединяем в нужном порядке, заканчивается `1`, закрываем `1`, открываем `2`... (повторить до конца всех строк)... сохранить соединённые строки (в массив быть может?) в результат.

Comment: да дубликат, в том вопросе мне посоветовали решать эту задачу на перл, еще до того как вы мне ответили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если считать, что изменяемые файлы помещаются в память целиком и их нужно перезаписать, то задачу можно решить следующим образом:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my @file_names = ('1.txt', '2.txt');
my $big_file_name = 'big.txt';

open(my $big_file, '<', $big_file_name) or die $!;
for (@file_names) {
    open(my $file, '+<', $_) or die $!;
    my $content = "";
    for (<$file>) {
        chomp(my $s = <$big_file>);
        $content .= $s . $_;
    }
    seek($file, 0, 0);
    print $file $content;
    close($file);
}
close($big_file);
```

Comment: @Mike Из вопроса это не очень понятно. Но если пишется продолжение, то да, `seek($big_file,0,0);` не нужен.

Comment: Да, Mike прав, в каждый следующий файл пишется продолжение большого

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с записью в новые файлы. Самое длинное оказалось получить правильно отсортированный список файлов. Регулярка поиска рассчитана на файлы от 0 до 29. Подправить по необходимости, что бы лишнего не брала.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(my $big,"<","big.txt") || die 'no big.txt';
for(sort {($a=~/(\d+)/)[0]<=>($b=~/(\d+)/)[0]} grep {/^[012]?\d.txt$/} <*.txt>) {
 open(my $fl,"<",$_);
 open(STDOUT,">",$_.".new");
 for(<$fl>) {
  chomp(my $l=<$big>);
  print "$l$_";
 }
}
```

Comment: Красиво. Мозговыносительно.